# No inserta registro de Maestro Detalle (o punto de venta) en mi codigo de Php, sugerencias del porque?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

he estado programando en Php y MySQL una práctica de maestro detalle el cual tiene como campos el "id_detalle_renta","idrenta","idauto", el cual inserta la renta, pero no el detalle de la renta, a continuacion el codigo de php con ciertas partes comentadas, me seria mucho su ayuda, gracias.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require 'bd/conexion_bd.php';


    if(!isset($_SESSION['status_renta']))
    {
        $_SESSION['status_renta']='Cerrada';    
    }

    //echo var_dump($_SESSION['status_venta']);
    //echo var_dump($_SESSION['ultimo_id']);

    $obj = new BD_PDO("usuarios");


    if (isset($_POST['btninsertardetalle'])) 
    {
        //if(!isset($_SESSION['status_venta']))
        //{
         if($_SESSION['status_renta']=='Cerrada')
         {
            $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion("insert into rentas(fecharenta,idusuario,idcliente) values(Now(),'".$_POST['txtusuario']."','".$_POST['txtcliente']."')");
            $_SESSION['ultimo_id'] = $obj->Ultimo_id();
            $_SESSION['status_renta']='Abierta';
         }

    $result = $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion("insert into detalle_renta(idrenta,idauto) values('".$_SESSION['ultimo_id']."','".$_POST['txtidauto']."')");
        /*}
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['ultimo_id']=0;
        }*/
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['btncerrarrenta'])) 
    {
        session_destroy();
        // header("Location: reporte_ticket.php");
        unset($_SESSION['status_renta']);
        $_SESSION['status_renta']='Cerrada';
    }

    // $datos = $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion("Select IdDetalleVenta, IdVenta,NombreProducto,IdProducto, Cantidad,Precio,( Cantidad*Precio ) as Subtotal  from tbldetalleventa inner join tblproducto on tbldetalleventa.IdProducto=tblproducto.id_Producto where IdVenta='".@$_SESSION['ultimo_id']."'");


    //$ticket = $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion("CALL ticket('82');");
    //echo var_dump($ticket);

 ?>
```

Comment: Has probado a imprimir con echo o var_dump los resultados que te van dando las diferentes consultas y los POST ? podría ser que que algún dato no te llegue o que la íltima id no la está tomando bien.

Comment: Depura tus variables: `var_dump($_SESSION['ultimo_id']);` por un lado y por otro: `var_dump($_POST['txtidauto']);`. También, verifica que no sea un problema de registro duplicado o algo así.